# Quickblox iOS download chat message attachment

Tags: ios, objective-c, quickblox, instant-messaging

I am working with the Quickblox iOS SDK for instant messaging. My app can send and receive pictures and other files as attachments. The documentation on the link below says to use the following method: - `[QBContent TDownloadFileWithBlobID:[attachment.ID integerValue] delegate:self]`

That method is currently deprecated. I'm using the recommended method `+[QBRequest*)downloadFileWithUID:(NSString *)UID ...]`

I pass in the Attachment ID as the UID here. That downloads some data, but is not the image data I am expecting. The documentation from that method says to use the blob ID of a `QBCBlob` object, not the attachment ID. I'm assuming that's why I'm getting invalid data. The docs don't state which ID to use here or how to get it. How do I get that from the attachment, and what is the easiest/best way to download the attachment data?

Documentation: http://quickblox.com/developers/Sample-chat-2.0#Receive_attachment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right link is http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-chat_users-ios

This is how download attachments using iOS SDK 2.0

http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-chat_users-ios#Receive_attachment

Setup a redirect to the previous one